# MySQL with large tables and high access - what is the next upgrade step?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in charge of a big website (one of largest in Brasil) for keep tracking of TV shows. Users can checkin/rate episodes make comments and so on. 
Site runs under PHP/MySQL on a dedicated server, but the current configuration is not handling the high access anymore.

The checkins table has 95 million rows, rates 30 million rows, almost 200k users. All accessing one single MySQL server shared with Apache. MySQL tuning has been my only task over the last months, but a next step needs to be taken.

I already have a second server (cloud with SSD storage) ready to go and I'd like some advice about the best thing to do.

Some options:

1. Only separate Apache from MySQL. One for each server.
2. Use proxy and load balance MySQL into the two servers.
3. Keep a second copy of database synced and do the queries on the read-only database, avoiding hit the main server.

Any other solution? I'm not a DBA, started this site from scratch, and now I'm facing the problem of getting big.

Comment: You could look into implementing some server-side caching in your site where possible on pages that access lots of data but where the data changes rarely. That way you don't always connect to the db.

Comment: If your database server and web server are on the same box, they may be fighting for disk access. Splitting them up would be my first option, since it is an easy step to take. Also, see if you can move one of them to an SSD drive - I'm not an expert, but I would expect that to help a great deal.

Comment: The new server is on a cloud with ssd, so i expect gains just separating Apache from mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you run on only one server is a big risk for such a website, so I would use the opportunity to create a failover solution as well as a faster database setup. You mention that most of your time goes to MySQL optimization, so I'll assume your PHP-site is not the problem. Also you don't mention if you use SSD. I cannot stress how important this can be for the performance, and given the amount of effort you are putting into optimization, and your website and the amount of users, I'll assume you run from old-fashioned hard disks.

So my recommendation would be:

- Start using SSD's. These will improve the DB performance at least ten times.
- Install Apache+MySQL on both servers, and mirror the MySQL server using multi master. This will give you two independent servers.
- Use IP failover to protect against hardware failures.
- Configure IP failover to automatically failover, but never go back.

You will get the most out of our servers and be protected against failures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have set a master-master solution, got some trouble with CpHulk blocking the connection between the servers (whitelisted later) , and synced. On the application side I'm making sure writes are all directed to the same server, and the selects can be splitted. I didn't set the IP Failover yet.  One more thing was using persistent connections  on some points that were using non-persistent connections .

Answer (score 0):

I would support your idea of load balancing. Keeping the second copy of db synced over seems redundant...it's basically a backup. I would pull the MySQL server off your apache server, load balance into two separate servers and you should see a performance increase.

Something like this is probably what you're looking for: https://www.howtoforge.com/loadbalanced_mysql_cluster_debian

Alternatively, start caching data.